# How to implement a constrained linear fit in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, constraints, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a linear model to a set of data, with the constraint that all the residuals (model - data) are positive - in other words, the model should be the "best overestimate".  Without this constraint, linear models can be easily found with numpy's polyfit as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-4.12179107e-01, -1.40664082e-01, -5.52301563e-06,  1.82898473e-01]
y = [-4.14846251, -3.31607886, -3.57827245, -5.09914559]

plt.scatter(x,y)
coeff = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
plt.plot(x,np.polyval(coeff,x),c='r',label='numpy-polyval')
plt.plot(x,np.polyval([-2,-3.6],x),c='g',label='desired-fit') #a rough guess of the desired result
plt.legend()
```

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCQfY.png)

Is there an efficient way to implement a linear fit with this type of constraint?

Comment: OK, isn't it always the case that the lowest error will be produced by a line through the two highest points?  You can't move the line any lower because of the constraint, and raising the line any higher is guaranteed to increase the error.

Comment: I don't think so. This would only work if the data has only one 'peak', like in my above example. This approach can fail to satisfy the constraint if there's more than one 'peak'.  Here's a counterexample: https://github.com/r-zachary-murray/Constrained-Linear-Fits/blob/main/Problem_Example3.ipynb

Comment: You're right, I should stop making suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quadratic programming problem. There are several libraries (CVXOPT, quadprog etc.) that can be used to solve it. Here is an example using quadprog:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quadprog

x = [-4.12179107e-01, -1.40664082e-01, -5.52301563e-06, 1.82898473e-01]
y = [-4.14846251, -3.31607886, -3.57827245, -5.09914559]

A = np.c_[x, np.ones(len(x))]
y = np.array(y)
G = A.T @ A
a = A.T @ y
C = A.T
b = y
coeffs = quadprog.solve_qp(G, a, C, b)[0]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, np.polyval(coeffs, x), c='r')
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: constrainted regression]

See e.g. [this post](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html) for more information. In describes, in particular, how to set up a linear regression problem as a quadratic programming problem.

As a side note, the optimal line will always pass through one data point, but it need not pass through two such points. For example, take `x = [-1., 0., 1.]` and `y = [1., 2., 1.]`.

Comment: Passes all my tests and is fast and efficient. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best fit is a line through the top two points.  I do an argsort to find the top Ys, compute the slope and y-intercept, and off we go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-4.12179107e-01, -1.40664082e-01, -5.52301563e-06,  1.82898473e-01]
y = [-4.14846251, -3.31607886, -3.57827245, -5.09914559]

plt.scatter(x,y)
coeff = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
model1 = np.polyval(coeff,x)
model1 += (y-model1).max()
print(model1)
print(sum((y-model1)**2))

z = np.argsort(y)
pt0 = (x[z[-1]],y[z[-1]])
pt1 = (x[z[-2]],y[z[-2]])
m = (pt1[1]-pt0[1])/(pt1[0]-pt0[0])
b = pt0[1]-m*pt0[0]

model2 = np.polyval([m,b],x)
print(model2)
print(sum((y-model2)**2))

plt.plot(x,model1,c='r',label='numpy-polyval')
plt.plot(x,model2,c='g',label='generated')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, but I don't think this is generally correct.  Consider the example where x = [1,2,3,4] and y = [2, 1,0, 2].  Numpy polyval will return the coefficient array [-0.1,1.5] with a corresponding sum of squares error of ~2.69.  Shifting the model like you recommend results in an SSE of 5.93.  Whereas a coefficient array of [0,2] runs through two points, passes my condition, and results in a smaller error (SSE=5).  Therefore shifting the line alone is insufficient to minimize the error subject to my constraint

Comment: Did you actually try that?  When I run those numbers, polyval produces (1.6, 1.2, 0.8, 0.4].  Mathematically, I believe my method HAS to produce a minimum error.

Comment: Here's an implementation of the counterexample.  https://github.com/r-zachary-murray/Constrained-Linear-Fits/blob/main/Problem_Example2.ipynb

Comment: You win this round.  I'll think about this.